# Return only numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, firebase

I have a database in Firebase, which I then convert to an array, this is my code:

```js
    let timeRef = firebase.database().ref('root/grupo0/user0/0');
    
    function snapshotToArray(snapshot) {
      let returnArr = [];
  
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          let item = childSnapshot.val();
          item.key = childSnapshot.key;
  
          returnArr.push(item);
      });
  
      return returnArr;
    };
     
    const timeRefArray = timeRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshotToArray(snapshot));
    });
```

Each element is like this: `^MED~@1550648873`

How can I return each element only with numbers?

Comment: can you share the structure of the arrays from which you wanna return each element only with numbers?

Comment: Does `childSnapshot.val()` return an object? Only then `item.key = ...` will work. So your goal is that `returnArr` is an array-of-objects?

Answer (score 0):

when returning each element to array you can use replace method:

```
str = item.replace(/\D/g,'');
returnArr.push(str);
```

then you can cut the non numeric part, before push it to your array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want just only the number included in the item string. Then, you need a regex to get the number. In your code, replace the line `returnArr.push(item);` with:

```
var m = /\d+/.exec(item);

if (m) {
  returnArr.push(m[0] * 1);
}
```

The `*1` is to cast the number to integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.match()` with a regex to extract the digit, then convert the result to a number with `parseInt`. You can then conditionaly push the item to the array if it is not `NaN`:

```js
const items = ['^MED~@1550648873', '^MED~@'];
const returnArr = [];

items.forEach(item => {
  const value = parseInt((item.match(/\d+/) || [''])[0]);
  !isNaN(value) && returnArr.push(value);
});

console.log(returnArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
var arr = [ '^MED~@1550648873','Am2mm55','^MED' ] ;
var patt = new RegExp('\\d+','g') ;

var result = arr.reduce( (acc, ele) => {
  if ( isTrue = ele.match(patt) ) { acc.push( isTrue.join('') ) ; }
  return acc ;
}, []) ;

console.log( result ) ;
```